# Why is my DKIM invalid?

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

When I use http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck to test my DKIM it says

```
This is not a good DKIM key record. You should fix the errors shown in red.

DNS query failed for 'key1._domainkey.board67.com':NXDOMAIN

A public-key (p=) is required
```

But I do have a public key
[image]

Now I am getting this error:

```
p=  MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvjT4cF+/SV69t38ihp7TOMZ2m ruxwtcicE/DmuZJdMcHuEmN9iN03Q8wMdU4TFeirkF79nJMh4wDma1N2LGUiOZrv j1YtCpKZZRlV0IAr7MtA7jjaBEGNU5EsWYcZXriGhkyzl39TXdVIaBuuuqWBN9lk pD+jlA6zCM3nPL6b1wIDAQAB

The p= field must be base64 encoded
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell without any context for the screenshot, but I think you've setup your DKIM record on `_domainkey.board67.com.board67.com`, instead of `_domainkey.board67.com`:

```
$ dig TXT _domainkey.board67.com +short
(no result)

$ dig TXT _domainkey.board67.com.board67.com +short
"t=y\;o=~\;"
```

You shouldn't be entering the full hostname in the first box - just the prefix. So the first box should just contain `_domainkey`, and the one below, `key1._domainkey`.

Comment: I made these adjustments and am now being told my p= field isn't base64 encoded??

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed your record and the error was because of the spaces( ) in the keys.  the key must be in a single line without space. Look closely and remove all spaces and it will work properly.

> p= 
>   MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvjT4cF+/SV69t38ihp7TOMZ2mruxwtcicE/DmuZJdMcHuEmN9iN03Q8wMdU4TFeirkF79nJMh4wDma1N2LGUiOZrvj1YtCpKZZRlV0IAr7MtA7jjaBEGNU5EsWYcZXriGhkyzl39TXdVIaBuuuqWBN9lkpD+jlA6zCM3nPL6b1wIDAQAB
>
> The p= field must be base64 encoded